# How do you react to unexplained downvoting of questions?

Tags: discussion

Historically, my presence on Stack Overflow hasn't exactly been very reputable. My questions has been downvoted enough for me to be unable to post even meta questions *multiple* times.

Since I didn't even have any conceptual knowledge of programming and development when I asked the first questions, it was natural that my dumb and unintelligible questions got downvoted. Of course not explaining the downvotes miffed me, it makes sense to send the questions to oblivion in hindsight.

But even my more recent questions, including [the one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48733089/modify-odoo-to-apply-product-cost-and-price-at-invoice-creation) I posted the day before yesterday got downvoted with nary a comment. Of course, I'm biased and consider my question legit in asking guidance on how to modify Odoo addons or documentations related to its source code. If the question is off-topic or worded wrong, please show me the way.

Comment: You can't be question banned in meta. Unless you were suspended.

Comment: IDK, I remember not being able to post when I couldn't on main SO either. Maybe I remember wrong.

Comment: In your question in SO: You are asking for an off-site resource, which is off-topic.

Comment: _shrug_ .........

Comment: As in, asking for relevant developer docs concerning the issue in question is off-topic?

Comment: Yes, it is off-topic. That's an offsite resource. You are asking for a link.

Comment: Yes, we can't maintain links to external resources. When the framework changes the URL to their docs the answer to that question becomes just another dead link making it even more difficult for others to find their docs later.

Comment: Regarding the title of this question: you are wrong in expecting comments explaining down-votes. That's not how it works. How do you react to unexplained down-votes? You work harder on your question.

Comment: ... I'm not solely asking for the link, it's a freakin' afterthought that I felt might be helpful to me.

Comment: Even if you remove the "a link to the docs" part, you are left with a question "looking for guidance", which is too broad, and also off-topic for the site.

Comment: Related: [Why isn't commenting mandatory on downvotes, and why are ideas suggesting such shot down?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/357436/why-isnt-commenting-mandatory-on-downvotes-and-why-are-ideas-suggesting-such-s)

Comment: This is the unfortunate effect of many people reacting badly after downvotes were explained and the moderators and community managers decided that instead of punishing the offenders it's much easier to just discourage explaining downvotes, so now as time passes less and less downvotes are explained.

Comment: I flag the mods since it's always serial downvoting by someone whom I've upset, (ie. closed their bad question:.)

Comment: @gnat Imo this is not a clean dupe. Instead of asking _when should I downvote_ it's asking _what should I do when I get downvoted_. There are some partial dupes, but most I could find are very localized, or focused on the downvoters and not the person receiving downvotes.

Answer (score 8):

Dealing with downvotes can be hard.

The cause of downvotes can be anything such as the question being unclear/not asking a question well enough, not abiding by the social standards (e.g. lots of thanks/fluff), using the wrong tags, too many tags or too few (but rarely too few), the question being off topic, [Tim losing his keys](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/215397/369403), invoking the [meta effect](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/235225/369403), etc.

The main thing you should do, in my opinion, is wonder: is my question well-formulated, well asked, on-topic, non offensive and not a dupe. For this objective, you can use the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/), section Asking.

If none of these apply to you, you can shrug it off. But people tend to have a reason for downvoting.

In this specific case, as yivi said, your question was off-topic, which is the most likely reason for the downvote.

Note that downvotes on the meta are far more frequent, and have a different meaning. Often, they're cast if similar questions have already been asked and this one doesn't form an interesting new discussion. On feature requests, burninate requests or other kind of requests, they can mean disagreement, and should be expected.

Note that there have been many, many questions and discussions about  downvotes, when to downvote, should we explain downvotes, etc.